# Remove LI from UL based on text within a SPAN

Tags: jquery

Given the following code:

```
<ul>
<li class="parent">
    <a href="#link">
        <span>Home</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="parent">
    <a href="#link">
        <span>Contact</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="parent">
    <a href="#link">
        <span>Blog</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

How can I check the value of the SPAN text, and if it equals "Blog," remove the entire LI from the UL?

The jQuery code I've been messing with is getting too complex, and I'm sure there's some kind of nested "find" approach that will help me solve this using minimal code.

Comment: "The jQuery code I've been messing with is getting too complex" At least show us what you've tried?

Comment: It was getting too convoluted, so I scrapped it. No point muddying the waters with bad code in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('span:contains("Blog")').closest('li').remove()
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qP854/)**

Comment: this would remove **My Blog** also.

Comment: @Dexa - Are you worried about it selecting the wrong span? Target it with a more specific selector then.

Comment: I like your simple solution, just gave heads up if someone wants exact value. There can be a lot spans containing word **Blog** in it, but not so much with just single word **Blog**

Comment: Perfect. Also, @Dexa, thanks for the heads up. In this case, the code will work because I don't have any other links with "Blog" in them, but it's a good caveat to keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$('ul li span').each(function() {
    if($.trim($(this).text())=="Blog") {
        $(this).closest('li').remove();
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q2meB/)**

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2E7VR/1/)

```
$("span").each(function() {
     if( $(this).text()=='Blog') 
      $(this).closest('li.parent').remove(); 
});
```